# Where is the class CryptoCommon in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cryptography, xamarin, commoncrypto

Im trying to use the CryptoCommon class but unable the find it in the monotuch assembly.

I found the assembly Mono.Security.Cryptography, does it have the same performance as the CryptoCommon class?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CommonCrypto** is used internally inside Xamarin.iOS, this is not something extra - i.e. there's no need to opt-in or opt-out.

What it means is that it's use is **totally transparent** to your code. If an algorithm is available in CommonCrypto then using the *classic* .NET type will use it.

E.g.

```
// this will use CommonCrypto. AES is supported by CommonCrypto
// if your device supports it AES can be hardware accelerated
var aes = Aes.Create (); 

// this will also use CommonCrypto. SHA-1 is supported by CommonCrypto
// if your device supports it SHA-1 can be hardware accelerated
var sha = new SHA1Managed (); 

// this will not use CommonCrypto since the algorithm is not supported by Apple
var r = RIPEMD160.Create ();
```

More [information](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/managed-crypto-vs-commoncrypto/) about CommonCrypto can be found on my blog.

Comment: Thanks u so much, I was actually looking at your blog already. I have to encrypt images in order to meet HIPAA regulations, which cypher algorithm do you consider is best  in this situation?

Comment: I've **never** read the HIPAA regulations so I do **not** know their requirements. Today most people use AES to encrypt data (128 to 256 bits) but the most important thing is *often* the key management (not the encryption itself).